# Are all URLs discoverable? Can you hide information safely in a random URL?

Tags: web-services, security, networking, web

I've been wondering about this for a while.

---

Let's say I have a web application at

> www.example.com

If there are n users of the application, could each person login simply using a URL?

E.g. For user 1 to access their part of the application, they would visit

> www.example.com/user/1

In this above case, the URL scheme is easily guessed.

But what if it can't be easily guessed?
E.g. For user 1 to access their part of the application, they would visit

> www.example.com/user/[random string]

---

**Are these random URLs discover-able?**

What I mean by random URL is a URL containing a very long string of random characters. If one used this URL as a password, it would be very difficult to guess.

And secondly, a more practical question--
**Can one assume that no one else has access to their part of the application?**

Or another way of asking, is guessing a random string the only way of accessing someone's part of the application?

---

The motivation for designing an application this way is that there would be no login/logout required.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Even if you put a random string in place of a user id, the same problem still exists. If someone guesses or somehow retrieves the random number of another user, he or she will still be able to access it.

What you are attempting is called security through obscurity. It is not a good plan to have your overall security based on hiding or obscuring sensitive data only.

> Are these random URLs discover-able?

Discoverable by search engine? That depends on your website settings. 
Accessible? Yes.

> Can one assume that no one else has access to their part of the application?

I am not sure what you meant by this, you will have clarify this part.